# use pretrained models in kaggle competitions with no internet

Tags: kaggle

So I tried following the style of having two notebooks one for training and one for inference, but I couldn't retrieve the trained models in the inference notebook.
to create the training notebook:
I went to https://www.kaggle.com/competitions/contradictory-my-dear-watson/code and clicked on new notebook
in this notebook I wrote the code to train the models and added this line to save the model

```
!mkdir {save_path}
model.save_pretrained(f"{save_path}/my_model")
tokenizer.save_pretrained(f"{save_path}/my_token")
```

and clicked on "save version" and checked the option the save output

to create the inference/test notebook:
I went to https://www.kaggle.com/competitions/contradictory-my-dear-watson/code and clicked on new notebook
in this notebook I ran the following cmd
`!ls /kaggle/working`
but I couldn't find the directory I created

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a private data set in Kaggle that holds the model files (`my_model`, `my_token`).  A Kaggle data set can hold any type of file.  Then in your inference notebook you can access this private data set and read the files.